# Proper inclusion of ideals localizes to a proper inclusion at one of the generators of the ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $f_1,...,f_n\in A$ be such that $(f_1,...,f_n)=A$.  Also let $I\subsetneq J$ be ideals. In exercise 5.3.H of Ravil Vakil's notes he suggest that we must have $$A_{f_i}I\neq A_{f_i}J$$ for some $i$  (where $A_{f_i}I$ is the ideal in $A_{f_i}$ generated by the image of $I$ under the natural ring homomorphism $A\rightarrow A_{f_i}$).  His hint is that $A\rightarrow \Pi A_{f_i}$ is an inclusion, which is easy to see.  How does one get $i$ for which $A_{f_i}I\neq A_{f_i}J$ from this though?

(Remark:  This seems easy to prove in the case that the ideals are finitely generated, since then the nonzero $A$ module $J/I$ must localize to something nonzero, $(J/I)_{f_i} \neq 0$, for some $i$.  And since Vakil's claim is only used to prove that (all $A_{f_i}$ are Noetherian) $\implies$ ($A$ is Noetherian), it seems one can assume the ideals are finitely generated since if there's an infinite ascending chain of ideals in $A$ then there's an infinite ascending chain of *finitely generated* ideals in $A$.  But i'd nonetheless like to know why this more general statement is true.)

Comment: This is an easy exercise (nothing is finitely generated here): If $M$ is an $A$-module and $M_{f_i}=0$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$ then $M=0$.

Comment: @user26857 yes, thanks. my brain was not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the commutative diagram

$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A/I @>{i}>> \Pi_i {A_{f_i}/IA_{f_i}} \\
@V{q}VV @V{q_l}VV \\
A/J @>{i}>> \Pi_i {A_{f_i}/JA_{f_i}};
\end{CD}
$

The horizontal maps are injective (you have already shown that). If $IA_{f_i}=JA_{f_i} \forall i $ then the map $q_l$ is an isomorphism and hence $q$ must be injective. Thus $I=J$